# Create a list of dates and avoid variable not set (VBA error 91)

Tags: vba, excel

I have financial data about certain stocks in five sheets and am trying to create a function which will calculate the exponential moving average of a given range.

[columns(1) = date ; columns(2) = closing price]

The arguments of this function are the number of days taken into account to calculate the EMA, and an integer `kol` to calculate several EMAs on several columns, side by side (no use for now). Here is my code so far:

```
Public Function MME(Lmme As Double, kol As Long)

Dim Cmme As Range
Dim Todate, rcell As Range
Dim alpha, period, Udate, i, j, k As Long
Dim Ustock As String
Dim wsDest As Worksheet

Udate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("UserForm").Range("B2").Value
period = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("UserForm").Range("B3").Value
Ustock = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("UserForm").Range("B4").Value

' MsgBox (Udate)

Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Ustock)
wsDest.Activate
With wsDest.Range("A2:A392")
  Set Todate = Cells.Find(What:=Udate, _
                     LookIn:=xlValues, _
                     LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                     SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                     SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                     MatchCase:=False)
  If Todate Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("todate wasn't found")
  Else
  End If
End With
i = Todate.Row
j = i + period
k = i - Lmme
Set Cmme = Range(Cells(i, 9 + kol), Cells(j, 9 + kol))
alpha = (2 / (Lmme + 1))
With Cmme
  For Each rcell In Cmme
    If rcell.Row <> i Then
          rcell.Formula = "=B" & rcell.Row & "*" & alpha & "+I" & rcell.Row - 1 & "*" & 1 - alpha & ""\
    Else: rcell.Formula = "=AVERAGE(B" & k & ":B" & i & " )   "
    End If
  Next rcell
End With
End Function
```

I created a list on a separate sheet which allows the user to select a date in 2008, and another which lets him select a Stock. So I did set new variables in order to do the trick but it doesn't work.

`Usaction`, `USdate` and `Uperiod` are the name ranges in which the values selected by the user are stored. But I got "error 91 or object required" on the `set = period`.

I really want the EMA to be calculated only for a specific period, starting the date selected. 
EDIT: I updated the code with the latest version i have. I still have an error 91 on endate
EDIT2: Code updated. I don't understand why the date is not found. On the sheet UserForm the date selected by the user is in "B2" (`USdate`). It is in format general, but with the CDate in the find function it should be considered a date right? I tried with the date format, it didn't change anything ...

EDIT3: Thanks to Branislav I managed to make the find works by switching every date to General format. Since the Find is working, anyway to make it work using date format? So that the user can see actual date, instead of the integer associated.

Another question: How can i bypass the Cells.Formula to operate directly within vba, and makes it so formula shows in the formula bar in excel once the code ran, except the result of SMAs and EMAs operation within the range?

Comment: When you get to the error line on `Endate`, what is `Todate` ? See in locals or in immediate or in watch window. As @freeman said, it's good practice to catch if the "Todate" is `Nothing` with simple `If Else` statement.

Comment: Also be careful with the `With` statement and placement of the dot `.`. For example in `Set Endate = Cells(Todate.Row + period, 1)`, the `Cells` have no dot, which means it will use default `ActiveSheet` parent, not necessarily your `wsDest`. Also I think you want `Cmme = ...` to be a range, you need to use `set Cmme = ...` to do that. Next little thing, when declaring variables you need to put `As <DataType>` behind every variable to declare it properly. [See section Declaring Many Variables](http://www.functionx.com/vbaexcel/Lesson03.htm)

Comment: You're right, I didn't do it cause i taught their would'nt be any problem as the user has to choose from a "valid date" list. 
I updated the code up there, so it seems the problem is with the find function as i get the msgbox (todate not found).

Comment: I want todate to be the cell containing the date selected by the user.
I got rid of the `endate` to keep it more simple, i'll create Cmme from todate. See up there.

Comment: There can be a problem, if the data types of `Udate` and values in `Range("A1:A392")` are different. For example the `Udate = 42090 (integer for 27.03.2015, try in excel =Today() and make it General format)` but the values in range are strings i.e. "27.03.2015". This way, the looked up value is not found.

Comment: Yes but isn't the CDate supposed to convert the integer `Udate = 42090`into a date? 
Anyway my last attempt the two are in format date so i removed the `Cdate`, and i still have a "no match". I fell this is because of the fact that it is in the middle of a `with ... End With`

Comment: That was not my point. The 42090 is a date, just written as integer. And you cannot find 42090 in values like "27.03.2015", "26.03.2015". **The point is the difference**. Make sure, the value you are looking up (`Udate`) can be found in the range. Don't get fooled by formatting. Check actual values while stepping through your sub. Hover over them or use debug windows.

Comment: Ok I see your point! I forced the format of range("A2:A392") for every sheet except userform, in format "dd/mm/yyyy". I tried to force the format of the cell in which the user select the date in the list. The list also comes from a range wich has been "format forced". But before the .find i msgbox the value of `Udate`and the integer still comes out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73938/discussion-between-branislav-kollar-and-mrj1m).

Answer (score 2):

`ToDate` is already a range

```
Set Endate = Todate.Row + period
```

Also, before you get to that point, you set `ToDate` by using `.Find()`. Since it's entirely possible that someone would enter an invalid date or a date that you don't have data for, I'd strongly recommend adding:

```
if ToDate is Nothing then
  'do some date not found stuff here
else
  'do your date found stuff here
End If
```

You may also want to consider changing `LookIn:=xlFormulas` to `LookIn:=xlValues` because I believe you're looking for a cell value, not a cell formula.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I updated the code i used, because i am now  using a list, so the user can't make mistakes. 
I alos changed the lookin:=xlvalues

Comment: Actually i think i should get rid of the endate, and do the refering with Todate, no? like that `Cmme = Range(Todate.Offset(, 9 + kol), Todate.Offset(period, 9 + kol))`          But it still lead to an error 91